# Let $|E|_e$ = $\infty$,E is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $|E|_i = |E|_e$ may be not hold

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

define the inner measure by $|E|_i = sup|F|$,where the supremum is taken over all closed subsets F of E.And $|E|_e$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

I know that if $|E|_e$ < $\infty$,then E is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $|E|_i = |E|_e$

But why $|E|_e$ = $\infty$ will cause the conclusion not hold?

Can you give some direction to solve it,thank you!!!

Comment: Do you mean $|E|_e$ is outer measure?

Comment: yes,$|E|_e$ is outer measure.

Answer (score 1):

I write a solution.Let us check it.

Choose nonmeasurable set A in (0,1)

Let E=($-\infty$,0) $\cup$ A

Then $|E|_e$=$\infty$ and $|E|_e=|E|_i=\infty$ , but E is nonmeasurable set.